# MPI_Wait give bad results

Tags: mpi

I have these two variants of the code that run but don't give good results, anyone can spot what's wrong.
Thank you for reading and for your help.

```
        if (me > 0)
        {
            MPI_Irecv(my_A, n, MPI_FLOAT, me-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            MPI_Send(my_A+n, n, MPI_FLOAT, me-1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        if (me < nprocs-1)
        {
            MPI_Irecv(my_A+n*(n/nprocs+1), n, MPI_FLOAT, me+1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            MPI_Send(my_A+n*(n/nprocs), n, MPI_FLOAT, me+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        // MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
```

the second variant using MPI_Waitall()

```
  MPI_Request request[2];
  MPI_Status status[2];
  MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
  MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &me );
  MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  request[1]= MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

    if (me > 0)
    {
        MPI_Irecv(my_A, n, MPI_FLOAT, me-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
        MPI_Ssend(my_A+n, n, MPI_FLOAT, me-1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if (me < nprocs-1)
    {
        MPI_Irecv(my_A+n*(n/nprocs+1), n, MPI_FLOAT, me+1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
        MPI_Ssend(my_A+n*(n/nprocs), n, MPI_FLOAT, me+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

MPI_Waitall(2, request, status);
```

PS: The code works correctly with MPI_Barrier(), but I want to use MPI_Wait().

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `rank == me`? Always MPI _Irecv() before you MPI _Send() . When `MPI_Waitall()` is used, you need to pass an array of 2 `MPI_Status`. Your first variant might overwrite the first request, and hence never wait on it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, yes rank = me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, yes rank = me. And the problem is if I do `MPI_request request[2]` and `MPI_status status[2]` and in `Irecv()` I do `&request[0] ` `&request[1]` and call `MPI_Waitall()` I get an error if I pass 2 as argument, it works only if I pass 1 as argument. @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: You need to pass `count-1` instead of `2`. Or pass `2` but initialize your `request[1]` to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL` so it is never used uninitialized.

Comment: I tried it as you can see in my updated post, but it still gives segmentation fault if I put `MPI_Waitall(2, request, status);` instead of `MPI_Waitall(1, request, status);`
And the latter gives inconsistent results that change every time I execute.
Thank you for your reactivity!

Comment: Please post a [MCVE], the error might be in the code you did not post.